# Proof of matrix form under invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $X$ be a nonempty set of elements in $A(V)$. The subspace $W \subset V$ is said to be invariant under $X$ if for every $M\in X$, we have $WM \subset W$. If $W$ is invariant under $X$ and is of dimension $r$ over a field $F$, prove that there exists a basis of $V$ over $F$ such that every $M \in X$ has a matrix in this basis of the form $\begin{pmatrix} M_1&0 \\ M_{12}&M_2 \end{pmatrix}$, where $M_1$ is an $r\times r$ matrix and $M_2$ is an $(n-r) \times (n-r)$ matrix.

I have no idea how to start solving this. Any hints to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $A(V)$?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a basis $x_1, \ldots, x_r$ for your invariant subspace $W$. You can extend this to a basis $x_1, \ldots, x_r, y_1, \ldots, y_{n-r}$ (in this order) for $V$. Let $M \in X$ and consider the matrix of $M$ with respect to this basis.